# ¿Cómo sé en qué columna está un texto determinado?

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo un fichero csv con separador de ":" y tengo que buscar en la primera línea un dato y saber la columna en la que está.

Lo tengo que hacer en un shell-script

Ejemplo

```
luis;34;madrid;españa
```

y quiero buscar madrid y saber que esta en la columna 3.

Comment: Puedes usar desde el shell script herramientas como `awk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si dentro del shell script puedes usar `awk`, es sencillo escribir un mini-programa awk que haga lo que buscas, y tomar la salida del mismo para guardarlo a una variable del shell.

Por ejemplo:

```
export CIUDAD=madrid
export FICHERO=datos.csv

columna=$(head -1 $FICHERO | \
    awk -F';' -v ciudad=$CIUDAD \
    '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i==ciudad) print i;}')

echo $columna
```

Con el comando `head -1` extraigo sólo la primera línea y se la paso a `awk` mediante el pipe `|`. Awk itera por los campos que tenga la línea (`NF` automáticamente contiene el número de ellos) y comprueba si cada campo (`$i`) es la ciudad buscada, en cuyo caso imprime el valor de `i`.

Todo ese comando entre `$()` hace que la variable `columna` recoja la salida, y por tanto tomaría el valor 3 en este caso.

Si la ciudad no apareciera en ningún campo de la primera línea, entonces `columna` contendría la cadena vacía, cosa que puedes luego testear si es necesario, por ejemplo así:

```
if [ -z "$columna" ]; then
    echo "Ciudad $CIUDAD no encontrada"
else
    echo "Ciudad $CIUDAD encontrada en posición $columna"
fi
```

Comment: me ha sido de gran ayuda tu respuesta. Funciona perfectamente

Comment: puedes usar `NR==1` para mirar solamente la primera línea